# My tableView scrolling freezes each time it reaches a new cell and has to load an image

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, asynchronous, uiimage

I have a tableView that has an imageView as a background, of which the image is either found in the Documents Directory, an NSCache, or downloaded from Firebase if it isn't found on the device. When downloading from Firebase there is no freezing, however when the cell is loading the image from the device, the scrolling freezes until it loads the image as the background image. I can't figure out why. Heres the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TripCell

    let trip = trips[indexPath.row]

    let path = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(trip.coverUID)
    if var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
        image = image.resizedImage(newSize: CGSize(width: (image.size.width)/2, height: (image.size.height)/2))
        cell?.updateUI(trip: trip, image: image)
        print("Loaded from DocumentsDirectory")
    } else if let data = TripsVC.imageCache.object(forKey: trip.coverUID as NSString) {
//This is mainly where it freezes
        var cachedImage = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        cachedImage = cachedImage?.resizedImage(newSize: CGSize(width: (cachedImage?.size.width)!/1.5, height: (cachedImage?.size.height)!/1.5))
        cell?.updateUI(trip: trip, image: cachedImage)
    } else {
        cell?.updateUI(trip: trip)
    }

    return cell!
}

func updateUI(trip: Trip, image: UIImage? = nil) {

    self.trip = trip

    if image != nil {
        print("Loaded from device")
        backgroundImage.image = image
        setLabels()
    } else {
//Doesn't freeze here
        let url = trip.coverPhotoUrl
        let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: url)
        ref.data(withMaxSize: 5*1024*1024, completion: { [weak self]
            (data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Couldn't download image")
            } else {
                print("Image downloaded from storage")
                if let imageData = data {
                    if var image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        image = image.resizedImage(newSize: CGSize(width: (image.size.width)/8, height: (image.size.height)/8))
                        self?.backgroundImage.image = image
                        self?.setLabels()
                        TripsVC.imageCache.setObject(imageData as NSData, forKey: trip.coverUID as NSString)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: because you're resizing the image in the main ui thread

Comment: So that should be done asynchronously? Where should I be doing that?

Comment: Checkout Alamofire Image - It's great! https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Comment: Very cool! How would that address this issue?